# javascript get the select dropdownlist internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-select

I have a 7 column table where the Edit mode is handle using javascript.
clicking on Edit in the row will make 2 columns editable. They change to a dropdown and a textbox respectively and Save Cancel options will show for that row.

Saving works on Firefox but not entirely on IE. IE does not get the value from the dropdownlist. it only saves the value from the textbox.

This is how I select the objects:

```
var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
var jqSelect = $('select', nRow);

jqSelect[0].value  
jqInputs[0].value   //This is the textbox and it Works
```

I must say the source code of the page shows  no sign of the select tag. (When it is already in Edit mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
 jqSelect.eq(0).val()
 jqInputs.eq(0).val()
```

You have to use jQuery val() function to retrieve the values of the elements...

Comment: Is the html update after an ajax call? IE doesn't show the updated html when doing a view source. But try inspecting the element with "IE Developer tools" and check the html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) jQuery function.

It normalizes the reading and setting of the values across browsers. It also works with `select` elements.

You code is not working, because when you get `jqSelect[0]` you actually have a DOM element. The `select` element does not have a `value` property. If you want to read the selected option from a select you will need to iterate over all `option` elements and find the selected one (via the `selected` attribute on the option).

This is actually what `jQuery.fn.val()` does. So use it like so:

```
var selectedValue = jqSelect.val();
```

Comment: @user1553087 Could you specify what exactly didn't work? Could you check that when you select the `select` element t actually finds it (with `length` property on the jQuery object)?